# Complex joins in Linq with multiple tables and LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction with this join.  I'm trying to convert some SQL to Linq. My SQL has a left outer join after several inner joins.  The following SQL produces the desired result:

```
SELECT TOP(50) [t].[TagFriendlyName] AS [TagName], [t0].[timeStamp] AS [LastSeen], [l].[Name] AS [LocationName]
FROM [Tags] AS [t]
INNER JOIN [tag_reads] AS [t0] ON [t].[epc] = [t0].[epc]
INNER JOIN [ReaderData] AS [r] ON [t0].[ReaderDataId] = [r].[Id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Readers] AS [r0] ON [r].[mac_address] = [r0].[mac_address]
INNER JOIN [Locations] AS [l] on [t0].[antennaPort] = [l].[AntennaId] AND [r].[Id] = [l].[ReaderId]
GROUP BY [t].[TagFriendlyName], [t0].[timeStamp], [l].[Name]
ORDER BY [t0].[timeStamp] DESC
```

My Linq code is as follows, but I can't figure out how to get the left outer join inserted properly. Not sure how to introduce the Readers table that needs the LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
var query = (
from tags in db.Tags
join tagreads in db.tag_reads on tags.epc equals tagreads.epc
join readerdata in db.ReaderData on tagreads.ReaderDataId equals readerdata.Id
join readers in db.Readers on readerdata.mac_address equals readers.mac_address

group tags by new { tags.TagFriendlyName, timestamp = tagreads.timeStamp, readerdata.mac_address } into grp

select new CurrentStatus()
{
TagName = grp.Key.TagFriendlyName,
LastSeen = grp.Key.timestamp,
LocationName = grp.Key.mac_address
}
)
.OrderByDescending(o => o.LastSeen)
```

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins) I need to use `DefaultIfEmpty()`, but I'm not sure where to introduce the Readers table.

Using EF Core 3.1.0.  THANKS!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should apply `Left Join` this way:

```
join readers in db.Readers on readerdata.mac_address equals readers.mac_address into readersJ
from readers in readersJ.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

The full code:

```
var query = (
    from tags in db.Tags
    join tagreads in db.tag_reads on tags.epc equals tagreads.epc
    join readerdata in db.ReaderData on tagreads.ReaderDataId equals readerdata.Id
    join readers in db.Readers on readerdata.mac_address equals readers.mac_address into readersJ
    from readers in readersJ.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join locations in db.Locations 
        on new { ap = tagreads.antennaPort, rd = readerdata.Id }
        equals new { ap = locations.AntennaId, rd = locations.ReaderId }
    group tags by new { tags.TagFriendlyName, timestamp = tagreads.timeStamp, readerdata.mac_address } into grp

    select new CurrentStatus()
    {
        TagName = grp.Key.TagFriendlyName,
        LastSeen = grp.Key.timestamp,
        LocationName = grp.Key.mac_address
    }
)
.OrderByDescending(o => o.LastSeen)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. How can I address joining of the table "Locations": 

After the left outer join I have another inner join:

INNER JOIN [Locations] AS [l] on [t0].[antennaPort] = [l].[AntennaId] AND [r].[Id] = [l].[ReaderId]

One of the values I need is from the Locations table.

Comment: @EltonSaunders But I wonder why you need that `LeftJoin`? you didn't use that at all and it can eliminated!

Comment: Thanks, yes my Linq attempt was missing the part where i used the field from the Locations table, but I'm pretty sure the `LEFT JOIN` was needed to get the correct value.  You got me going!  I had one issue with an Id column type mismatch, but that was outside the scope of my question and the IDE made it clear where the issue was. THANKS!!!